# Double range query on one column uses wrong seek predicate

Tags: sql-server

This problem comes up in the real world, but is already present in the following trivial example. I am using SQL Server 2017.

Given a table with only one non-id column, which takes only one value:

```
create table #test (id bigint not null, status smallint not null)

/* Populate with 10000 times value 10 */
;WITH numbers(Number) AS
(SELECT 1 AS Number
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Number+1 FROM numbers where Number<10000
)

insert into #test (id,status)
select number,10 from numbers option(maxrecursion 10000)

/* Create fresh index */
create index index_status on #test ([status])
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ("tempdb..#test", 'index_status') WITH HISTOGRAM
```

Now we query a double range on this column (0 results, since the only value is outside both ranges):

```
select 1
from #test
where status < 10
and status <> 2
```

The chosen execution plan uses an Index Seek, with

- Seek Predicate "status < 2 AND status > 2"
- Predicate "status < 10"

and consequently needs to read all 10000 rows. This surprises me, since I can read off the index statistics to conclude that a Seek Predicate on "status < 10" would be more efficient, since this already filters out all rows.

**Question:** Why are Seek Predicate and Predicate chosen 'the wrong way'?

I am not interested in alternatives or workarounds, I am only interested in understanding this choice of execution plan. For example we can rewrite the query using a UNION ALL on both range queries seperately, forcing two efficient Seek Predicates:

```
select 1
from #test
where status < 2

union all 

select 1
from #test
where status > 2 and status < 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Running

```
dbcc traceon (3604,8606)
```

And then the query with a `#temp` table the final tree before cost based optimisation looks as follows (with the `NE/ <>` predicate first and the `LT/ <` predicate second) - the deviation of the predicate order from the "Input tree" happens from the "Simplified Tree" stage and stays that way in subsequent trees.

```
*** Tree After Project Normalization ***
        LogOp_Project

            LogOp_Select

                LogOp_Get TBL: #test #test TableID=-1583795211 TableReferenceID=0 IsRow: COL: IsBaseRow1001 

                ScaOp_Logical x_lopAnd

                    ScaOp_Comp x_cmpNe

                        ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [#test].status

                        ScaOp_Const TI(smallint,ML=2) XVAR(smallint,Not Owned,Value=2)

                    ScaOp_Comp x_cmpLt

                        ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [#test].status

                        ScaOp_Const TI(smallint,ML=2) XVAR(smallint,Not Owned,Value=10)

            AncOp_PrjList 

                AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1003 

                    ScaOp_Const TI(int,ML=4) XVAR(int,Not Owned,Value=1)
```

With a permanent table the tree looks as follows.

```
*** Tree After Project Normalization ***
        LogOp_Project

            LogOp_Select

                LogOp_Get TBL: test test TableID=645577338 TableReferenceID=0 IsRow: COL: IsBaseRow1001 

                ScaOp_Logical x_lopAnd

                    ScaOp_Comp x_cmpLt

                        ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[test].status

                        ScaOp_Identifier COL: ConstExpr1004 

                    ScaOp_Comp x_cmpNe

                        ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[test].status

                        ScaOp_Identifier COL: ConstExpr1005 

            AncOp_PrjList 

                AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1003 

                    ScaOp_Const TI(int,ML=4) XVAR(int,Not Owned,Value=1)
```

The second case is quite fragile. Adding a query hint - such as `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` it reverts to the first case. It seems to retain the initial order of the predicates, as written in the query, in the cases that simple parametrisation is attempted (this is not attempted for the temp table `#test`).

[image]

`select 1 from test where  status <> 2 and status < 10` gives the "bad" plan again with the seek on `<> 2` and residual on `< 10`

[image]

My supposition is that the index matching code just picks the first seekable predicate available in input tree order in the rare case that there are multiple competing seek predicates for the same column.

Specifically the `SelPredNorm` transformation rule appears to cause the predicate re-ordering. The following gives the desired plan.

```
select 1
from #test
where status < 10
and status <> 2
option (queryruleoff SelPredNorm);
```

As for why this does not kick in (in this case) with auto parameterised queries that question is still not addressed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The SelPredNorm-hint is interesting. My 'real-life' example does use a permanent table, and I am pretty sure I tried interchanging the order of the < and <> without effect. Also I was not aware of differences in plans between (freshly created) temporary and permanent tables, are you aware of any general guidelines regarding this?

Comment: It seems to be the case that in this specific example when the query is auto parameterised the predicates don't end up getting reordered from the query text. When using a #temp table the query isn't auto parameterised. Which makes sense I guess as auto parameterisation is about reuse of execution plans and scope for this on queries accessing local temp tables is limited. There is also an example here of disabling auto parameterisation on the perm table https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282793/why-using-a-local-temp-table-instead-of-a-global-temp-table-or-a-regular-table/282834#282834

Comment: I don't see any general guidelines here. Just looks like an edge case

Answer (score 2):

After running some more tests I got to the conclusion that it might be a bug. That behavior only happens if you use a Local Temporary Table. When using a Global Temporary Table or a common table the Query Optimizer generates the plan you expected.

**Index seek info when using a common Table:**

[image: common table index seek info]

**Index seek info when using a Global Temp Table:**

[image: global temp table index seek info]

As we can see, the Query Optimizer can choose the most efficient execution plan, but there's something going on with the behavior of the local temp table.

---

Since understanding if there's is any difference between a local temp table and a global temp table or a regular table that could influence this behavior is another subject, I've opened another question:

[Why using a local temp table (instead of a global temp table or a regular table) influences the Query Optimizer to choose a poor query plan?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282793/why-using-a-local-temp-table-instead-of-a-global-temp-table-or-a-regular-table)

Comment: It doesn't "use that info when you're not using a local temp table" - it just uses as the seek whichever one appears first in the query text - this is not based on stats